# Problemas com instalação Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

Sempre quando vou tentar instalar o Node aparece essa mensagem. Alguém pode me ajudar? Antes eu já tinha o Node instalado, mas fui tentar baixar e instalar novamente. Isso porque queria instalar o Angular (que também não consegui)

Agora quando digito "node -v" no prompt de comando aparece "'node' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opa KennedyRMenezes, tenta instalar uma versão mais antiga, estava tentando instalar a LTS 14.17.2 porém estava tendo esse mesmo erro. Solução instalei a 14.16.0.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, estava arrumando as coisas para formatar o computador. Vou testar sim. Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Você baixou aqui: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-x64/ ? Eu baixei, mas quando vou na linha de comando e digito node -v não aparece versão nenhuma. Se puder me dizer como vocês fez ajudaria demais. Ele não segue aquelas etapas de instalação só abre uma linha de comando.

Comment: Olha, consegui baixar.

Answer (score -3):

Basta executar o CMD em modo administrador, e colcar esse comando abaixo

```
   net localgroup /add "Authenticated Users"
```

e depois na instalação do node clicar em retry que ele vai continua a instalação.